# Executing OLAP functions with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, olap, hivecontext

I am working with spark version 1.6. I want to execute OLAP functions include CUBE, ROLLUP, GROUPING SETS through sql queries on Spark. I understand that the cube and rollup functions are available on the dataframe api but how can I execute them through SQL queries?

Do I need to use HiveContext for this? Do I need to have Hive setup for that? How do I persist the dataframe as a table that could be accessed by the sql query executed using HiveContext?

It would be great to have a look at an example code. Thanks.

Comment: You can perform queries using the sqlContext only See here : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically

Comment: Those would be simple queries not including the functions I mentioned - CUBE, ROLLUP, GROUPING SETS, right?

Comment: You can implement it as it has already been implemented : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6356

Comment: Just read the whole data in the DF and then register it as a temp table then use spark.sql("<<SQL Query>>"").show to print the output !

Comment: That doesn't work @Shivansh Srivastava. I have tried it already. I get an error on zeppelin stating the rollup function is undefined.

Comment: Have you imported the functions !

Comment: How do you do that? Have you tried executing these?

Answer (score 1):

At ActiveViam we also needed to do interactive OLAP queries on Apache Spark. So we made an extension called [Sparkube](http://activeviam.com/sparkube) that exposes a Spark dataset as a multidimensional cube, without moving the data.

Once your dataset is exposed that way, you get access to all the OLAP MDX functions directly on top of Spark, including [DRILLDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/drilldownlevel-mdx), [DRILLUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/drilluplevel-mdx)

Here is for instance how you mount the content of a CSV file in memory and expose it as a multidimensional cube:

```scala
// Load a file into a Spark dataset.
// Here we load a CSV file, get the column names from
// the CSV headers, and use Spark automatic type inference.
var ds = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("inferSchema","true")
  .load("path/to/file.csv")

// Import the sparkube library (the sparkube jar must be in the classpath)
import com.activeviam.sparkube._

// Expose the dataset as a multidimensional cube.
// You can start visualizing the cube right away at http://localhost:9090/ui
// or connect from Excel with the XMLA protocol at http://localhost:9090/xmla
new Sparkube().fromDataset(ds)
  .withName("My first cube")
  .expose()
```